# How do I create and use restore points in Arch Linux (or Linux in general)?

Tags: arch-linux, backup, restore

I am relatively new to Arch Linux and I really like its rolling-release concept.

Before I do a system update via `pacman -Syu`, I want to create a *restore point*. So that if my system update should fail, I can go back to the last good state my computer was in before the attempted system update.

This is because once when I did a `pacman -Syu` on my Arch install, it b0rked my system and wouldn't boot. It happened when I still had minimal to no essential files on my computer so I did a fresh install. But now that I sort of slowly built a system much to my liking, I don't want to reinstall it from scratch and do all the things I have already done again should a system update break it. With a *restore point*, I can most likely restore my computer without the hassle of reinstalling everything.

How do I create, and use, *restore points* in Arch Linux?

Answer (score 8):

Arch isn't designed to work like that: it is a rolling release, so you are always going to have to continue to upgrade packages as they are pushed to your repo: the only alternative is to freeze everything.

Having said that, what you are asking can best be managed, *within the Arch framework* by doing two things:

1. updating regularly (so that you are only upgrading small numbers of packages at a time) and using the logs in `/var/log/pacman.log` to provide a list of packages to rollback if something does go wrong.
2. Not clearing the cache of packages prematurely, or—if you need the space—before you do issue a `pacman -Sc` or `pacman -Scc`, then backing up `/var/cache/pacman/pkg/` to an external drive so that you have access to older versions if you do need to downgrade a package or packages.

If you are not running the `[Testing]` repo, then the reality is there is very little in the way of breakage and when it happens it is well-documented. As [wojox noted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15103/how-do-i-create-restore-points-in-arch-linux-or-linux-in-general/15111#15111), reading is a prerequisite for maintaining a well-running Arch Linux installation.

For Linux in general, you can use a tool like [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) to make snapshots of your current install.

**Caveat** All of the above is referring to your system. You should, of course, have a regime in place to back up your data.

Answer (score 4):

Linux distros in general are not set up with anything like a restore system. There are small exceptions. The RPM based distro I use keeps an archive of all previous versions of packages when they are upgraded. It's possible to install those packages and roll the software back to what it was before an upgrade, but this creates dependency chaos and is less useful than it sounds. Usually the only way out of package problems is forward.

However if you wanted to implement a system wide restore system, **the way to do this would be through the file system rather than the package manger**. Use a file system such as XFS that allow full file system snapshotting. Or better yet, setup your drives with LVM and use any file system you like. A slightly more manual way would be the `rsnapshot` tool to make incremental backups.

Before you do major system work, snapshot the whole thing. Then if something goes bad, you can roll back to exactly how it was and try again.

Answer (score 3):

The two things I do in Arch is [READ BEFORE UPGRADING](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=57205)

and [Downgrading Packages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Downgrade_packages). I don't know of any restore point :).

Answer (score 2):

It's going to depend on the filesystem you're using, not just the OS or package manager.

If you run `/` on btrfs, you could leverage its snapshot ability to do this.

I've only *just* started in with Arch, but as an example of what could be done: Ubuntu has [apt-btrfs-snapshot](https://launchpad.net/apt-btrfs-snapshot).  It's a relatively simple script that hooks into `apt` to create a btrfs snapshot right before installing packages, and also gives users the ability to easily list/create/delete/rollback snapshots.  Of course, all this only works if `/` is on btrfs.  With 11.04, the installer is smart enough to put `/` and `/home` on separate subvolumes even if they're on the same partition, so snapshot rollbacks don't affect `/home`.

Answer (score 1):

### Manually

[Arch: safely save and restore pacman databases](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345659/arch-safely-save-and-restore-pacman-databases/345676#345676) outlines a manual approach to saving a snapshot of the packages in the official repositories. You could use this approach combined with saving a filesystem snapshot for the package data. My understanding is that only the latest versions of the packages are kept in the repositories.

### Using `aura`

[`aura-bin`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/aura-bin/) makes it easy to rollback/restore a `pacman -Su` sytem update/upgrade.

#### Save current state

To save the list of installed packages and versions:

```
aura -B
```

#### Restore previous state

Select a previous restore point from date-stamped list:

```
aura -B --restore
```

#### Clean up old restore points

To remove all but the last 3 restore points:

```
aura -Bc 3
```

#### Manjaro users

If you're running Manjaro, remove the `PKGBUILD` dependency on `abs` when running `yaourt -S aura-bin`.