# Arch: safely save and restore pacman databases

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, manjaro, lock

I want to backup the `pacman` sync databases after an execution of `pacman -Sy`, creating "restore points" which `pacman -Suu` can use to reverse a failed system upgrade. Further background can be found [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/pacman-su-rollback-strategy/17365).

I want to manually lock the pacman databases via`/var/lib/pacman/db.lck` to ensure that the databases are not changed while being saved / restored.

How to I atomically check/create `/var/lib/pacman/db.lck`?

Comment: You don't. Let pacman do its job.

Comment: @jasonwryan pacman doesn't do the job of saving and restoring versions of databases, so I don't follow you.

Comment: *You* don't restore databases; you restore packages and let *pacman* update the database accordingly.

Comment: I've updated the question to explain why I do want to restore databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Locking the databases

`mkdir` is an atomic operation which will avoid concurrency issues.

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/pacman/db.lck 2>/dev/null && echo Got lock || echo Locked out
```

I tested the above while running `pacman -Syy` in another shell. The output is "Locked out" while pacman is running, and "Got lock" after it completes.

Reciprocally, `pacman -Syy` will say that it can't lock the database while the directory exists.

#### Backup

I wrote a paranoia_level=9 [`bash` script](https://gist.github.com/HaleTom/9dbffaf3369b86ca272ffe6a61a36aba) which safely saves the sync databases to directories under `/var/lib/pacman/backup` named by ISO8601 date.

The script also saves non-dependency packages lists of:

- all packages
- sync packages
- foriegn (eg AUR) packages

#### Usage of backups

Uset the `-b` option to specify a different location for the databases, eg:

```
pacman -Suu -b /var/lib/pacman/backup/2017-02-26T12:55:26+07:00
```